# Button activating automatically?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a button that on a gui that supposed to open a new gui and close the old one but as soon as I run the code it automatically opens the new gui without closing the old one. I also have a button on the new gui that supposed reopen the old gui and close the new one. How can I fix this?

```
public class IA2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{



JButton total = new JButton();
JButton back = new JButton();

JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();


 IA2(){
        
         
        frame1.setTitle("Lab equipement");
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setLayout(null);
        frame1.setSize(500, 425);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setResizable(false);
        frame1.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(5, 25, 50));

                frame2.setTitle("Total Equipement");
            frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame2.setLayout(null);
            frame2.setSize(500, 425);
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.setResizable(false);
            frame2.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(5, 25, 50));
          
        total = new JButton();
        total.setBounds(50, 10, 150, 75);
        frame1.add(total);
            total.addActionListener(this);
            total.setText("Total Equipement");
                total.setFocusable(false);    

                back = new JButton();
            back.setBounds(50, 10, 150, 75);
            frame2.add(back);
            back.addActionListener(this);
            back.setText("Back");
            back.setFocusable(false); 
}



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
    if(e.getSource()==total) {
            
    frame1.dispose();
    frame2.setVisible(true);
            
    if(e.getSource()==back) {

    frame2.dispose();
    frame1.setVisible(true);    
            }   
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Why does the constructor make both frames visible if you only want one visible?

Comment: unrelated: null layout is __wrong__!

Comment: please fix the indentation of the code - also for your own sake:) - looks like the brackets in the actionPerformed are misplaced

Comment: Don't use multiple frames, make use of something like `CardLayout` instead to switch between individual components - then, you only need one frame

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead.

```java
   public class IA2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   
   
   
      JButton total = new JButton();
      JButton back = new JButton();
   
      JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
      JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
   
   
      IA2(){
      
      
         frame1.setTitle("Lab equipement");
         frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame1.setLocationByPlatform(true);
         frame1.setVisible(true);
         frame1.setResizable(false);
         frame1.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(5, 25, 50));
      
         frame2.setTitle("Total Equipement");
         frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame2.setLocationByPlatform(true);
         //frame2.setVisible(true);
         frame2.setResizable(false);
         frame2.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(5, 25, 50));
      
         total = new JButton();
         frame1.add(total);
         total.addActionListener(this);
         total.setText("Total Equipement");
         total.setFocusable(false);
      
         back = new JButton();
         frame2.add(back);
         back.addActionListener(this);
         back.setText("Back");
         back.setFocusable(false);
         
         frame1.pack();
         
      }
   
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      
         if(e.getSource()==total) {
         
            frame1.dispose();
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.pack();
         
         }
         
         
         if(e.getSource()==back) {
            
            frame2.dispose();
            frame1.setVisible(true);
            frame1.pack();
         }
      }
   
   }
```

I made `frame2` invisible on startup.

I also fixed your `actionPerformed` method by pulling out the if statement out of the other.

Comment: null layout is __wrong__ - don't replicate the errors in the question

Comment: Ok, removed the layout

Comment: still wrong (though without much effect): manually setting sizes/locations of components

Comment: Ok, used `Window::pack` and `Window::setLocationByPlatform`